# Visual Studio Code Integrated Terminal: http-server : The term 'http-server' is not recognized

Tags: node.js, npm, httpserver

I am new to Angular and hence Visual Studio Code. I started with my first Angular application by following online tutorial. When I tried to execute http-server on VS code integrated terminal, I got the below error. I could not find, how to resolve.

> PS C:\MyFolder\Learning\Angular> http-server
>   http-server : The term 'http-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
>   was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + http-server
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (http-server:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run this from within the terminal:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

What this will do is install the latest version of `http-server` globally on your computer. Then you can run it from the terminal, or another command prompt, when you need to serve a web application.

See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) for more information on the package, and how to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. previously I didn't try installing globally.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! If you are having trouble with tsc, please ask new question.

Comment: I'm using Win 10 and installed it using the command globally "npm install http-server@0.11.0 -g". It worked once. After I restarted my machine next day, I started getting the error mentioned in the question above. Can someone please help? I can find http-server here: C:\Users\USERID>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\http-server

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed it globally?

`npm i -g http-server`

To be able to use a package in your terminal you need to have it installed globally on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

HI I got the same error but I fix it  work also for when you use  live server --->
In your visual studio code editor [click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayxNW.png)

press icon shown in the image and then install HTTP-server/live-server
now open your HTML file as for right click on the file and select option open as live-server . now it's fine...

THANKS----

Answer (score 0):

you can install with this:

```
npm install http-server
```